# Krull dimension of affine algebra is equal to maximum of transcendence degrees

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

I'm going through some introductory books on commutative algebra and I'm struggling with the following problem:

Let $A$ be a non-trivial affine algebra over the field $K$. Since $A$ is noetherian, we know that the zero ideal of $A$ has only finitely many minimal prime ideals: let's call them $P_1,...,P_n.$ For each $i = 1,...,n$, let $L_i = \mathrm{Quot}(A/P_i)$ where $A/P_i$ are integral domains. So we can look at $L_i$ as an extension field of $K$.

Now I have to show the following:

i) $\dim(A) = \max\{\mathrm{tr.deg}_KL_i: 1 \leq i \leq n\}$.

ii) If $\dim(A) = \mathrm{tr.deg
}_KL_i$ for all $ i = 1,...,n$, then $\mathrm{ht}(P) +\dim(A/P) = \dim(A)$ for all $P \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$.

What I know so far, are the following properties:

- $\dim(A) \geq \mathrm{ht}(P_i) + \dim(A/P_i)$ for $i = 1,...,n$.
- I think that $\mathrm{ht}(P_i) \leq 1$ since these are minimal prime ideals of
  the zero ideal.
- if an integral domain $E$ is an affine algebra over $K$ with $L=\mathrm{Quot}(K)$ then $\dim(E) = \mathrm{tr.deg}_KL$.

I'm not sure if these properties are enough to solve the problem.
Is it possible to  view the integral domains $A/P_i$ as affine algebras over $K$, so we can use the 3rd property?

Comment: i) Don't you think that $\dim A=\max_i\dim A/P_i$?

Comment: ii) Use that $\dim A=\dim A/P_i$ for all $i$, and  $\mathrm{ht}(P) +\dim(R/P) = \dim(R)$ for all $P \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ when $R$ is an affine domain.

Comment: for i), I do think so, but how do I show equality, since I don't know if A is an integral domain or not? Can I just show that for every prime-ideal chain in $A$, there is one at least as long in $A/P_i$?